# How can I change the value of something using the arrow keys?

Tags: matlab

I have created a value of `d = 20`.  I would like `d` to increase by `10` every time I press the right arrow key and decrease every time I hit the left arrow key.  So If I pressed the right arrow key once then `d = 30`, and if I pressed the right arrow key again then `d = 40`. And then if I pressed the left arrow key then  `d = 30`.

Should I use `WindowPressKeyFcn`?

Comment: How would I assign it to the arrow keys though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = 20;

f = figure;
k=1;
while k
    waitforbuttonpress;
    if get(gcf,'CurrentCharacter')==28     % Detection for left key
        d=d-10
    elseif get(gcf,'CurrentCharacter')==29 % Detection for right key
        d=d+10

    elseif get(gcf,'CurrentCharacter')==32
        k=0;   % Stop execution if Spacebar is pressed
    end
end
close(f)   %Closing the figure window
```

This will open a figure window. Press <kbd>**→**</kbd>  or <kbd>**←**</kbd> keys to increase or decrease the value by 10 respectively. The execution will stop if you press <kbd>**Spacebar**</kbd> .

**P.S:** Your figure window should always be on [focus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_(computing)).